# hadoop your endpoint configuration is wrong

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I know this has been asked many times but for the life of me I can't setup Hadoop properly on my machine to run the simplest example. I'm following the tutorial on [this link.](https://blog.devgenius.io/install-configure-and-setup-hadoop-in-ubuntu-a3cdd6305a0e)

bash-rc:

```
#Hadoop Related Options
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_OPTS"-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
```

hadoop-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH+=” $HADOOP_HOME/lib/*.jar”
```

Here are my xml files:
core-sit.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
<description>The default file system URI</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
  <value>0</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>    <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PERPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I've configured the SSH as mentioned in the link, performed namenode format and started everything using start-all.sh. After which this is the output from `jps` command:

```
11568 ResourceManager
11689 NodeManager
14845 Jps
13311 SecondaryNameNode
```

But when I try to put a single text file in hdfs, I get this error:

```
amol@Ubuntu:/usr/wc_project$ hadoop fs -put hashtags.txt /hdfs/input
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 55: export: `/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*.jar”': not a valid identifier
2023-02-24 18:02:30,805 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: Your endpoint configuration is wrong; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnsetHostnameOrPor
```

I'm doing it for a class, please help me set up Hadoop. :(

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0 is not a valid address for the `fs.default.name` that the client can use. This is not a routable IP.

The wiki in the error mentions this - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/UnsetHostnameOrPort

You should use the value from `hostname -f` instead, or `127.0.0.1` if running on one machine.

Same applies to the YARN resource manager host value.

Regarding your other errors, you don't need to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`